# How to name an arbitrary sequence of things in a macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I am trying to use `?` in a macro, matching an arbitrary keyword:

```
#![feature(macro_at_most_once_rep)]

macro_rules! foo {
    (
        pub fn $name:ident (
            & $m : $( mut )? self
        )
    ) => (
        pub fn $name (
            & $m self
        ) {}
    )
}

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    foo!( pub fn bar(&mut self) );
    foo!( pub fn baz(&self) );
}

fn main() {}
```

I tried varied syntax, but they all failed. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick would be to insert a repetition with a dummy token.

```
#![feature(macro_at_most_once_rep)]

macro_rules! foo {
    (
        pub fn $name:ident (
            & $( $(@$m:tt)* mut )? self
        )
    ) => (
        pub fn $name (
            & $( $(@$m)* mut )? self
        ) {}
    )
}

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    foo!( pub fn bar(&mut self) );
    foo!( pub fn baz(&self) );
}

fn main() {
    (&mut Foo).bar();
    (&mut Foo).baz();
    // (&Foo).bar(); //~ERROR cannot borrow
    (&Foo).baz();
}
```

Comment: What is the `@` used for? I cannot find it in the documentation

Comment: It's an arbitrary dummy token to force the inner repetition repeat 0 times. I chose `@` just because it's unlikely used.

Comment: Specifically, it's a *common* dummy token used in macros for "internal" implementation details.